# How can I get to see tomorrow's 'special' April Fools questions even though I will be offline for 2 weeks?

Tags: discussion, april-fools

I am going to be on holiday from tomorrow morning until 17th April - I won't have (and don't want!) any internet access as soon as I leave.

What is the best way to ensure that I get to see tomorrow's inevitable April Fools questions? I am happy to wait until I get back before I see them (ie I'm not asking someone to print them out and post them to me).

Answer (score 4):

> "I ... don't want! ... any internet access"

You must correct your priorities! [:-)

or

> subscribe a RSS feed and leave a browser running to collect the messages...
>  (search a tag: at the bottom of the page you'll find the link)

Answer (score 3):

Get 10k reps before you leave, so you can see deleted questions.

Comment: Current priorities are: 1) packing. 2) getting 10k reps. Unlikely that 2 is going to get completed.

Comment: @Rich, don't worry, there is a lot of posts tagged [april-fools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/april-fools), so probably you would still see some when you back.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that will poll the rss feed of the site and archive the posts for you as they happen.  You probably shouldn't poll it more than once every five minutes or so, and some things will slip through the cracks, but it's probably the easiest way to be sure you'll get most of everything.

Comment: I can't believe you're making the dangerous assumption that I know how to progra...oh, wait...

Comment: @Rich Scripting isn't *programming!*

Comment: That's very true...

Comment: @Rich - I use the Brief add-on for Firefox - no need for a script!